# How to maintain the end state of a neon animation in Polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way to persist the final state of a neon animation? I have tried to use `fill: 'forwards'` but doesn't seem to be doing anything.

```
  <template>
    <div id="rect" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:red"></div>
  ...

  properties: {
    animationConfig: {
      value: function () {
        return {
          'hide': [{
            name: 'fade-out-animation',
            node: this.$.rect,
            // this doesn't work!
            fill: 'forwards'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Basically I want the `div` to be hidden after the `hide` animation finishes. You can see in the [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGmJge) that the red `div` fades out but then appears right after the animation finishes.

Comment: How about setting the `hidden` attribute to that node after `on-neon-animation-finish`?

Comment: @zerodevx thought about this but it gets very complicated n messy when you have many dependent animations.

Comment: Yes it gets complicated - and doing so might cause FOUC as well. It doesn't help that `neon-animation-finish` debounces; can't actually tell which node in a sequence is complete.

Comment: `neon-animation` is still a WIP. For simple transitions, can consider skipping the API completely and use CSS classes.

Comment: @zerodevx yeah if it's not supported I will go with web animations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down to the source of the issue.

Open `neon-animation-runner-behavior.html` and find the `playAnimation` function.

Inside `this._player.onfinish`, note `this._player.cancel()` is called. This `cancel` basically

> Set source to null and clears all effects associated with the previous
>   source content.

**Update**

In the end, I added another parameter to the `playAnimation` function, so whenever I need to force to maintain the end state, I add a `false` flag to the function like this -

```
this.playAnimation('unloadCells', null, false);
```

This is the safest option I have come up so far as it won't interrupt with the existing Polymer animations within different elements. I'm sure the Polymer team will be able to come up with a much solution in the future but for the time being this does the trick. :)

```
playAnimation: function (type, cookie, cancellable) {
  // default its value to true so existing stuff won't be affected
  cancellable = typeof cancellable !== 'undefined' ? cancellable : true;

  var allConfigs = this.getAnimationConfig(type);
  if (!allConfigs) {
    return;
  }
  var allAnimations = this._configureAnimationEffects(allConfigs);
  var allEffects = allAnimations.map(function(animation) {
    return animation.effect;
  });

  if (allEffects.length > 0) {
    this._player = this._runAnimationEffects(allEffects);
    this._player.onfinish = function() {
      this._completeAnimations(allAnimations);

      if (this._player) {
        // when manually set to false, this._player.cancel() will be skipped 
        // so we get to maintain the end state for some scenarios
        if (cancellable) {
          this._player.cancel();
        }
        this._player = null;
      }

      this.fire('neon-animation-finish', cookie, {bubbles: false});
    }.bind(this);

  } else {
    this.fire('neon-animation-finish', cookie, {bubbles: false});
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a listener to detect the end of the animation. Then, call a function that hides the div.

```
properties: {
  animationConfig: {
    value: function () {
      return {
        'hide': [{
          name: 'fade-out-animation',
          node: this.$.rect,
        }]
      }
    }
  }
},

listeners: {
  // this event is fired when the animation finishes
  "neon-animation-finish": "animationComplete"
},

animationComplete: function() {
    this.$.rect.style.display = "none";
}
```

If you have many different animations that you need to listen for the ending of, use a switch statement to separate each animation.

```
properties: {
  animationConfig: {
    value: function () {
      return {
        'hide': [{
          name: 'fade-out-animation',
          node: this.$.rect,
        }]
      }
    }
  }
},

listeners: {
  // this event is fired when the animation finishes
  "neon-animation-finish": "animationComplete"
},

animationComplete: function(event, animHandler) {
    switch (animHandler) {

        case "hide":
                this.hideFinished();
                break;

        case "show":
                this.showFinished();
                break;

        default: null

    }
},

hideFinished: function() {
//do something
},

showFinished: function() {
//do something
}
```

When using this technique, you have to add a second parameter to the `playAnimation` function, which acts as an identifier. Like this:

```
this.playAnimation("hide", "hide");
```

Then for each animation you add, simply add another case to the switch statement with the value in the second parameter of the `playAnimation()` function. I usually use the same string to keep it easy to track.

Comment: I am doing exactly like this currently. And it gets really messy when you have to play animations on child elements...

Comment: @JustinXL, How exactly did you tackle the child elements issue? I'm running into the same headache by the sounds of it.

I have 'animatables' which I want to wait on to finish to then trigger the exit animation of the parent element. So there is no opportunity to leverage the technique as above using the playAnimation function.

How did you tackle this? (I'm on Polymer 1.x btw)

Comment: @JustinXL, just to add, the most feasible way of doing this in my mind is to llisten for the animation to finish on the parent element, then fire an event back on the child and handle everything there